# CPU throttling not working as intended on Dell Precisiom 5530

Tags: dell, intel, cpu, 19.04

Sometimes when I start to drag and drop Firefox tabs, or a file/folder in Nautilus on Ubuntu 19.04, the whole system freezes, I cant move my mouse or interact with the system. It catches up after about 2-5 seconds.. I am pretty sure this is due to CPU throttling

```
dmesg -T
```

returns

```
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU11: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 126508)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 126495)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839849)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839884)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839780)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839912)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839772)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839918)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839856)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839915)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839891)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839914)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839910)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 839917)
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU11: Core temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[Wed Jul 17 17:02:38 2019] CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
```

for the time of the a freeze
I'm pretty sure it"s not normal to have that many events on one CPU

edit: It sometimes happens when opening terminal or Firefox as well

Running `watch sensors` and in another terminal `stress --cpu 8`
gives me the temperatures:
before:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        4890 RPM
fan2:        4909 RPM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +62.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +63.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +65.0°C
```

during:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        4890 RPM
fan2:        4909 RPM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +97.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +94.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +95.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +97.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +94.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +90.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +93.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +70.0°C
```

and after:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        4915 RPM
fan2:        4915 RPM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +69.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +69.0°C
```

It almost instantly went up to the 90°C+ and stayed constant until I stopped the `stress` command, after which it took about 20 sec to cool back down.

Running `sensors` right after turning the screen back on and logging in after 1 hour of no usage:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        2496 RPM
fan2:        2499 RPM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +47.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.0°C
```

and after idling after about 10 min:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        3688 RPM
fan2:        3706 RPM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +55.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.0°C
```

Comment: In one terminal run `watch sensors` to see the temps, in another run `stress --cpu 8`.  Post the before, during and after temps and about how long it takes for the temp to reach its peak and drop back down to normal.

Comment: @rtaft added the output to the post

Comment: do you hear your fans change speed at all?  What is your idle CPU usage like?  It looks like your fans are on full speed even when idle, and your idle temps are pretty high.

Comment: @rtaft yeah I can hear them speed up a bit. I don't know how to check the cpu usage, but I have attached the sensors output after letting the laptop sit for an hour.

Comment: Most likely the fan and fan port is either plugged with debris or the fan is about to give out. You can easily check for debris by removing the bottom of the laptop and cleaning out the fan and the area around the air intake. If its full of hair/dust/trash, you'll have your answer. If not, post back and we can try something else. This may be a dumb question, but its not setting on carpet or anything is it? Needs to have unobstructed access to airflow from underneath.

Comment: At full usage, your system can't cool fast enough.  Maybe the airflow is blocked some, maybe the fan/heat sync isn't mounted properly, maybe the laptop design just sucks.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. It only started after the 19.04 upgrade. I don't have the "package temperature" errors, and I cleaned out my CPU fans a few days ago. It happens in all sorts of apps, anything where I can click and drag something, and sometimes for no reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

Originally thought this might be a blocked fan issue (and it may be), but these laptops are very robust. I actually have the same model. It has two fans and looking at the report you posted they are spinning fast enough to potentially allow the laptop to take flight so that isn't the issue. Looking around, I found several post of people complaining of the same issue and possibly pointing to defective thermal paste application from the factory. Here is a link [Precision Laptops overheating](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Dell-Precision-5520-runs-hot-and-shuts-down-occasionally/td-p/6060275)

If you feel comfortable doing it, you can remove the bottom and the heat sinks, clean off all the old thermal paste and apply something like Arctic Silver instead. Definitely check first with Dell to avoid voiding your warranty. So, first check that fans aren't blocked and laptop has access to airflow. Check out the forum post I linked to do a Google search yourself for "Precision 5530 Overheating" and try the thermal paste reapply as a last resort. If still under warranty, contact Dell and see if there is a recall or if they will provide a replacement.

Comment: I'll try to talk it out with dell, thank you for your advice!